# How do I perform a redirect to the cart?

Tags: commerce

I'm trying to redirect the user to the cart from a custom page using the following code.

```
return new RedirectResponse(\Drupal::url('cart'));
```

Is there a function to go directly to the cartrce? If not, what is the route name for the cart page?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Devel module, you could also find the right routes on "/devel/routes".

An then do something like:

```
  $url = Url::fromRoute('commerce_cart.page');

  //$url->toString();
  $form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is saying *custom page*, I take the redirect is not done on a form. If the controller handling the page extends the [`ControllerBase`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Controller%21ControllerBase.php/class/ControllerBase/8.6.x) class, the code to redirect users to the cart page is similar to the following one.

```
// Put the following line at the top of the file containing the controller class.
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

// This is the controller method that handles the custom page.
public function redirectToCart() {
  $this->redirect('commerce_cart.page');
}
```

There isn't any need to conver the route name in a URL object: [`UrlGeneratorTrait::redirect()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Routing%21UrlGeneratorTrait.php/function/UrlGeneratorTrait%3A%3Aredirect/8.6.x) (from the `UrlGeneratorTrait` trait used from the `ControllerBase` class) accepts the route name as first argument.

Redirecting from a form require different code. Supposing the form class extends the [`FormBase`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormBase.php/class/FormBase/8.6.x) class, you would use the following code.

```
// Put the following lines at the top of the file containing the form class.
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

//This is the form method that handles the form submission.
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state->setRedirect('commerce_cart.page');
}
```

If the route requires parameters, `UrlGeneratorTrait::redirect()` and `FormState::setRedirect()` accept them as second parameter (an array).

The route name for the cart page is shown on the first line of [modules/cart/commerce_cart.routing.yml](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce/tree/modules/cart/commerce_cart.routing.yml).

```
commerce_cart.page:
  path: '/cart'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\commerce_cart\Controller\CartController::cartPage'
    _title: 'Shopping cart'
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Symfony Component for redirect

```
  $url = "/cart";
  $response = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse($url);
  $response->send();
```

If you want route name you will get with following code

```
$url_object = \Drupal::service('path.validator')->getUrlIfValid('/cart');
kint($url_object->getRouteName());
```